# Is the memory of the pointer freed when I set it to NULL?

Tags: pointers, memory, memory-leaks

When I run this code, are the variable msg and its value "Hello" deleted from the memory?

```
Message *msg;
msg->value = "Hello";
msg = NULL;
```

Thanks
V.

Comment: This looks like C++ or C, but I'm not 100% sure. This behavior depends on the language.

Comment: I dont see any memory allocation to "msg". So, running this program might crash.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++, setting a pointer to `NULL` (or any other value, for that matter) does not automatically free the space that the pointer previously pointed to. You must call `free(msg)` before reassigning the pointer, to avoid leaking memory (unless the memory is still in use via some other pointer variable).

However your code never assigned anything to `msg` in the first place, so there's nothing to leak. The assignment `msg->value = "Hello";` dereferenced an uninitalized pointer, which has undefined behavior.